# cant ssh to hostname of server, but can ip

Tags: ssh, freebsd

On a local LAN I am unable to connect to my FreeBSD8 server with OpenSSH.  I can on the other hand ssh directly by IP address and it works fine.

The server as well as my workstation are behind the same NAT router which is the DNS relay/delegator to my isp.  I have my hostname bound to my localhost in /etc/hosts.

Do I need to set up a local nameservice?  Id like to rectify this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you'll need to put a host entry for the freeBSD8 server on your local machine. i.e. in `/etc/hosts` add a line `<BSD_IP>    <BSDNAME> (<BSD_FQDN)>`